# Data Frame com as informações do Banco Central do Brasil

Tags: python, pandas

Criei uma função para coletar os dados do Banco Central separando por variáveis que eu desejo trabalhar. Agora queria criar um data frame que tivesses todas essas informações, mas não estou conseguindo, se alguém poder me ajudar agradeço.

```
def consulta_bc(codigo_bc):
    url = 'http://api.bcb.gov.br/dados/serie/bcdata.sgs.{}/dados?formato=json'.format(codigo_bc)
    df = pd.read_json(url)
    df['data'] = pd.to_datetime(df['data'], dayfirst = True)
    df.set_index('data', inplace = True)
    return df.loc['2015-01-01' : '2020-09-01']

pib = consulta_bc(4380)
tx_selic = consulta_bc(4390)
desemprego = consulta_bc(24369) 
m1 = consulta_bc(27791)
igpm = consulta_bc(189)

data = [[pib, tx_selic, desemprego, m1, igpm]]

index = pd.date_range(start = '2015-01-01', end = '2020-09-01', freq = "M")

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = [['Pib', 'Selic', 'Desemprego', 'M1', 'IGP-M']], index = index)

df
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Descrevendo o problema geral você vai conseguir apenas uma resposta geral. Exemplo: "Como construir uma casa?", "Use blocos e cimento, construa paredes sólidas.". Em vez disso pergunte algo específico e respondível de forma útil: "Como levantar uma parede usando esse tipo de bloco com tal inclinação e de tal altura de forma segura?", resposta: "Posicione os blocos no formato tal, execute esse algoritmo de colocação de blocos, não use essa ferramenta pois há o risco tal, aqui tem um exemplo funcionando de uma parede pronta para você ver como faz [link]". Vê? Perguntas muito amplas não ajudam.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como seus dados já são `DataFrame`s com os mesmos índices, você pode simplesmente concatená-los por coluna usando [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```py
data = [pib, tx_selic, desemprego, m1, igpm]
df = pd.concat(data, axis=1)
df.columns = ['Pib', 'Selic', 'Desemprego', 'M1', 'IGP-M']
```

Output:

```
                 Pib  Selic  Desemprego         M1  IGP-M
data                                                     
2015-01-01  481097.2   0.94         6.8  333454078   0.76
2015-02-01  466951.8   0.82         7.4  330708611   0.27
2015-03-01  508621.8   1.04         7.9  327928960   0.98
2015-04-01  493434.8   0.95         8.0  319444733   1.17
2015-05-01  491259.3   0.99         8.1  318441737   0.41
...              ...    ...         ...        ...    ...
2020-05-01  560059.1   0.24        12.9  503444375   0.28
2020-06-01  605146.9   0.21        13.3  534044506   1.56
2020-07-01  631040.8   0.19        13.8  536124166   2.23
2020-08-01  629988.0   0.16        14.4  553487667   2.74
2020-09-01  630706.5   0.16        14.6  565442300   4.34

[69 rows x 5 columns]
```